# Don't know how to write the Javadoc for this short method

Tags: java, api, recursion

I need to write a Javadoc comment for this method:

```
public static int maxDigit(int n) 
{ 
    if (n < 0) return maxDigit(-n);
    if (n < 10) return n; 
    return n % 10 > maxDigit(n / 10) ? n % 10 : maxDigit(n / 10);
}
```

Basically, it returns the largest digit of a number. For instance, if n=36920 it will return 9. But I don't know how to write the inside's method documentation

i tried to write it but i don't know if it's correct could you help?

```
if (n < 0) 
    //in case of n<0 returns -n to the method in order to make the number  positive
    return maxDigit(-n);
    // checks if the number is a digit 
    if (n < 10) 
    return n; 
    //calls the maxDigit method with n - one digit every time , until n<10
    int max = maxDigit(n / 10);
    // checks if the remainder of n/10 is bigger than max
    return (n % 10 > max)? n % 10 : max;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
/** Find the largest digit in decimal representation of given number.
 *@param n The number to search in
 *@return The largest digit
 */
public static int maxDigit(int n) 
{ 
    if (n < 0) return maxDigit(-n);
    if (n < 10) return n; 
    int max_ = maxDigit(n / 10)
    return n % 10 > max_ ? n % 10 : max_;
}
```

Is this what you meant?
By the way, I optimised the method for you a little. Now it won't cause tree-recursion.

Comment: Yes! 
and how would you write the documentation inside the method?
don't find  a way to write it

Comment: You write it above the method. The javadoc should automatically apply to the function bellow it.

Comment: About the inline method: The last line is not obvious. What is the mathematical formula behind that logic? Also it should mention that this method is implemented using recursion.

Comment: I copied it from the question. It takes the last digit and comares it to the result of calling the same function to the rest of the number. After that, it returns the bigger value. It's not optimal solution though. EDIT: I optimised the function a little ;)

Comment: @DorianGray The last line is corrent, because untill n<10 you call all the time the same method . if n%10>f(n/10) so - return whats bigger..
this way, the number is losing a digit everytime and at the end when it has only 1 digit, the tail is going back up and than it compared between
n%10 and the given number of(n/10) back up

Comment: @Hume2 how would you comment the last line of the method i just explained?
i don't know how to  express it with words

Comment: @Jordan_boy I never said it is incorrect, it would just require an explanation like you said above.